# Formatting code with <pre> tag in React and JSX

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to use the pre tag inside of JSX.When you use the pre tag in JSX, it doesn't format at all. Why? In order to use the pre tag I need to do something like this:

```
const someCodeIWantToFormat = "var foo = 1"
const preBlock = { __html: "<pre>" + pythonCode + "</pre>" };
return(
  <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={ preBlock } />;
)
```

Why?

Comment: i would implement that in this way: 

`const someCodeIWantToFormat = "var foo = 1";

const preBlock = (<pre> pythonCode  </pre>);

render(){
  return (<div>{this.preBlock}</div>)
};`

im using es6

Comment: Ooops. Yeah, I just realized I typed it wrong. In my code, I have it the way you described

Answer (score 103, accepted):

### Use template literals

[Template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) allow the use of multi-line strings which preserve leading/trailing white-space and new lines.

```js
const pythonCode = `
    print(
        "Hello, World!"
    )
`

class PreFormattedCode extends React.Component {
    render() {
      return <React.Fragment>{pythonCode}</React.Fragment>
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<PreFormattedCode />, document.getElementById('code'))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<!-- The content rendered into this tag will preserve whitespace -->
<pre id="code"></pre>
```

Answer (score 19):

**Gfullam** has a posted a great answer.

I'll expand it a bit and provide some alternative solutions. Most of these are *probably* overkill for your *particular* case. However I believe you (and potential future readers) might find these useful. **Note that these require ES6.**

---

### Template Literal Expression

Since you already have your code stored in a variable, you could use a Template Literal Expression. This is might be preferable if you have many variables or if you want to control your output.

```js
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
   render() {
     var foo = 1;
     var bar = '"a b   c"';
        return (
          <pre>{`
            var foo = ${foo};
            var bar = ${bar};
          `}</pre>
        )
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <SomeComponent />, 
  document.getElementById('content')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

Perhaps not needed in this particular implementation, but it might be good to know that also can do function calls and other operations within the brackets.

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/gMMNGZ)

---

### Tagged Template Literals

If you don't want to manually add line-breaks, semi-colons and other code formatting for your `<pre>` tag, you could use a Tagged Template Literal to return the right output for you. Just provide it with the variables to output!

```js
class SomeComponent extends React.Component {
  pre(strings, variables) {
    return variables.map((v, i) => {
      return `var ${v.name} = ${v.value};
`
    })
  } 
  
  render() {
     var variables = [{name: "foo", value: 1},{name: "bar", value: '"a b   c"'}];
     return <pre>{this.pre`${variables}`}</pre>;
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <SomeComponent />, 
  document.getElementById('content')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="content"></div>
```

*PS: Isn't this awesome!?*

[**CodePen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZOOdML)

Answer (score 13):

A good way to format in jsx is to use `String.raw` with a template literal and then the `pre` tag in your jsx. This helps eliminate any escape issues if you're doing something like this.

I did this for a starwars api project in React. This was my header.

```
    const Header = () => {

        var title = String.raw`
             ___| |_  ___  _____ __      _  ___  _____ ___
            / __| __|/ _  |  __/ \ \ /\ / // _  |  __// __|
            \__ | |_  (_| | |     \ V  V /  (_| | |   \__ |
            |___/\__|\__,_|_|      \_/\_/  \__,_|_|   |___/
        `;
        return (
            <div>
                <pre> {title} </pre>
            </div>
        )
    };

    export default Header;
```

Answer (score 10):

use

```
<pre>
  {JSON.stringify(yourdataobject, null, 2)}
</pre>
```

to render objects

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    <Row key={i} className="question">
      <Col xs="12" className="article" >
        Article {article + 1})
      </Col>
      <Col xs="12">
        <pre>{`${v.QuestionDesc}`}</pre>
      </Col>
   </Row>
```

Hope for help.