# How to render JSX code between <pre> tags

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I have a textarea where users can write code. Usual HTML tags (strong, p, b, etc) are rendered without any problems.

Now I would like to use [this twitter embed component](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-twitter-embed)

But as I see, it does not render anything on the screen.

This is the function that takes the inputted code from the textarea.

```
function parseHTMLContent(content) {

    var wrapper = document.createElement('div');
    var div = wrapper.innerHTML= "<pre>"+content.toString()+"</pre>";

    return(div);

}
```

And this is how I render it.

```
<div className="article_content" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: parseHTMLContent(this.state.content)}}>
</div>
```

How can I handle it like this when someone inputs this Twitter Embed component that it would render as it should.

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37847885/formatting-code-with-pre-tag-in-react-and-jsx

Comment: Have you tried replacing `content.toString()` with something like `<strong>test</strong>` just to help narrow down where the issue is?

Comment: What exactly is this.state.content? Did you check that it contains proper markup? Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve .