# Bootstrap 4 - react - multiline code block

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, create-react-app

Using react 16 - with create-react-app, and bootstrap 4, I can't get a pre/code block to be multi-line with a react app.

Besides the react part, this is written per Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/content/code/#code-blocks

I have verified this works correctly (is multiline) in a straight HTML app, so something is making it not work in my create-react-app environment (webpack,babel?).

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import "./App.css";
class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {/* prettier-ignore */}
        <pre>
          <code>
&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href="#" class="text-primary"&gt;Primary link&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href="#" class="text-secondary"&gt;Secondary link&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href="#" class="text-success"&gt;Success link&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href="#" class="text-danger"&gt;Danger link&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href="#" class="text-warning"&gt;Warning link&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href="#" class="text-info"&gt;Info link&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href="#" class="text-light bg-dark"&gt;Light link&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href="#" class="text-dark"&gt;Dark link&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href="#" class="text-muted"&gt;Muted link&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href="#" class="text-white bg-dark"&gt;White link&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
          </code>
        </pre>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Running this produces this:

[image]

In chrome inspector it looks like this:

[image]

How do I get the pre/code block to render multiline?

Comment: Use a <br> tag?

Answer (score 0):

Add `<br />` element when you want a new row.
Like this:

```
&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href="#" class="text-primary"&gt;Primary link&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;<br />
&lt;p&gt;&lt;a href="#" class="text-secondary"&gt;Secondary link&lt;/a&gt;&lt;/p&gt;<br />
```

Comment: you shouldn't have to do that when wrapped with a PRE tag - https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_pre.asp, and I am following bootstrap's documentation

Comment: ok, then a more elegant solution would be this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37847885/formatting-code-with-pre-tag-in-react-and-jsx

Comment: yes that was the answer I was looking for. Looks like my question is really a duplicate.  I appreciate your help and directing me to this answer.